# Java applet crashes when I try to crop a picture

Tags: java, applet

I've been trying to chop up a larger picture and use it as tiles for a game. I had the program working using fillRect() to simulate the image. However, when I replace the fillRect code, it crashes. Here is what I've been using:

```
buffer.drawImage(section[i][j].getSectionImage(i, j),
  sectionSize * i + OFFSETx,
  sectionSize * j + OFFSETy,
  this);

public class Section{
   private static ImageIcon ii;
   private static Image mainImage;
   private Image sectionImage;

   public Section(){
      if (ii == null){
         ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("images/Mossy_rocks.png"));
         mainImage = ii.getImage();
      }
   }
   public Image getSectionImage(int x, int y){
      sectionImage = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(mainImage.getSource(), 
         new CropImageFilter(1,1,20,20))); //test values
         return sectionImage;
   }
}
```

I tried "extends JApplet/JFrame/JComponent" for the Section Class, but it didn't seem to help.

Edit: I would also like to mention that if I would just return mainImage from getSectionImage(), I get the image. I think the biggest problem is the rest of that function... but I'm not sure, so I included everything I needed to add when replacing fillRect().

Comment: Any exception is the console?

Comment: what line does it crash on? what are the values in the variables?

Comment: Sorry. I suppose I used the wrong terminology. It just hangs. No error. No anything. As I'm recreating the error, I notice a few things: the createImage() can only be used if you extend the Section class. And, that is where the problem occurs. If I extend Section with JApplet or JFrame, and comment out all other relevant code, it stops working. Even worse, cleaning the project isn't enough. Once its stops working, I can't change the code and try again... I have to reboot and try again.

Comment: I don't have an answer except to say there are zero checks here to see if the image can be found or if any of the variables are null, on top of that this happens inside the constructor! Not good. I'd move this code into another method and at least check to see if the image was found or not before trying to call something like
 
mainImage.getSource()

Check the result of getResource() 

    `if(null != getClass().getResource("images/...")) {  
    // found image  
    } 
  
Finally you should log important events, e.g. image found or not, even System.out would be better than having no logging

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, eon. I already checked to see if the image can be found, but writing it into the code would be a good idea. If I simply return mainImage rather than use the sectionImage = createImage(blah), I get a working product. Of course, its the full sprite sheet, not just the 20x20 section that I'm asking for. Of course, like I said, extending the class itself that seems to be the problem (I don't need to extend the class if I'm not using the createImage()).

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better way to crop this image.  Here is how I did it:

```
screenImage.drawImage(Image sprite,
                 int (x position on screen),
                 int (y position on screen),
                 int (x position on screen + width),
                 int (y position on screen + height),
                 int (x position from sprite),
                 int (y position from sprite),
                 int (x position from sprite + width),
                 int (y position from sprite + height),
                 null);
```